# Mobile applications and web service data transfers (WCF and JSON)

Tags: android, json, wcf, mobile

I'm looking for some best practice concepts as far as transferring data between a mobile device (Android right now, but concepts apply pretty much to the rest as well). I currently have a WCF service set up with a working JSON endpoint. I'm starting to modify the existing service methods with the appropriate WebGet/Invokes, etc to make it RESTful. The service implements the request/response pattern so that all communication between a client and the service are wrapped in a complex MessageRequest and MessageResponse object.

What is the best way to have a mobile application successfully utilize this pattern? There are only two solutions I can come up with, each with their own pros and cons:

1. Create all the data transfer objects in the client project, and then create a JSON/DTO mapper (GSON might work well here). Use the client-side objects to handle all client data management until a server request is necessary, go DTO-to-JSON, and send the request to the server. The upside here strikes me is that it makes client-side data management easier because it parallels the service domain. The downside is that these have this has the potential to breakdown the more complex an object becomes.
2. Ignore the DTOs client side and just do everything straight from the JSON. The upside here is that it removes the overhead associated with the larger objects and the required mapping. The downside here is that this strikes me as being very brittle - any changes to the returning object need to be handled deep in the code, rather than just making the change to the client side DTO and mapper.

Is there a better way to accomplish this data exchange? Or are these the only real ways to handle it? How do you manage data transfer in your mobile applications?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar WCF setup as you do, and I ended up creating very lightweight data objects client side. These manage pulling apart a `JSONObject` representing themselves and create any sub-objects they need, but aside from that are simple classes mostly used to group data together and contain no business logic. We haven't yet needed to do any client side caching, but these objects would be a great place to put in SQLite code to persist themselves out.

It has worked great so far, and we were even able to port the client-side Android code to another project running regular Java just by including `org.json`.